# Eclipse do not show my custom attributes (attrs.xml)

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, custom-attributes

Using Eclipse, I created a simple Android project containing a custom component (MyTextView, inherited from **android.widget.TextView**).
After I created the file, attrs.xml where I added an attribute to this class, as specified below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyTextView" >
        <attr name="AttributeOne" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I added an object in my **main.xml** linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mt="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/myprogram.custom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <myprogram.custom.MyTextView
        android:text="MyTextView"
        android:id="@+id/myTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </myprogram.custom.MyTextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I open the **main.xml**, and choose the tab 'Graphical Layout', selecting my component, the custom attribute does not appear in the tab 'Properties' of the Eclipse, but the original attributes of class inheritance (**android.widget.TextView**) appears. 
This is a mistake? What is the procedure to submit my custom attributes?
Or I'm mistaken?

Thank you.
Luciano.

Comment: Did you try closing your project and opening it again ? I noticed that for the themes that the Graphical Layout in Eclipse doesn't seem to update (when you add themes) unless I reload the project.

Comment: Yes, and still does not work ...

Answer (score 2):

I just restarted Eclipse and it worked! :D

Comment: Yay, what a SOLUTION! That means, when thinking you've done right it appears to be wrong so you might redo your code to infinity although all you need to do is restart the enviornment - which is what is the whole problem with Eclipse. You can work on a bug that doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

To allow the [Android Developer Tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html) to interact with your view, at a minimum you must provide a constructor that takes a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) and an [AttributeSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html) object as parameters. This constructor allows the layout editor to create and edit an instance of your view.

```
class PieChart extends View 
{
    public PieChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

or if still not solve then You can do this in your Custom View:

```
if(!isInEditMode())
{
   // Your custom code that is not letting the Visual Editor draw properly
   // i.e. thread spawning or other things in the constructor
}
```

detail of [**isInEditMode**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isInEditMode%28%29)